# Understanding req.flash()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connect-flash

I am still confusing about using req.flash in nodejs.

I have .catch like..

**Login function**

```
.catch(function(e){
  req.flash('errors', 'error here')
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

So this is I make a custom request object with property flash?

And because I'm using redirect, now the response object will send the request with custom request to the '/' route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using [req-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/req-flash).

If you use `req.flash()` in the controller of your '/' endpoint, you'll get the following object:

```
{
  errors: 'error here',
}
```

You can then do whatever you want from this point.

A common case of usage is to use this to display messages conditionaly. For instance, you can display an alert if `req.flash().errors` is defined.